# Use Toast Notification in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I created a custom control 'Toast Notification' in WPF and i want to use it in MVVM to display messages, but i don't know where implement it (MainWindow or each page) and how send messages from each page to toast notification. Please help me to fix this problem.

[image: my toast notification control]

```
public class Toast:Control
{
    static Toast()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata (typeof (Toast),new FrameworkPropertyMetadata (typeof (Toast)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate ();
        ChangeVisualState ();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Text",typeof (string),typeof (Toast),new PropertyMetadata ("Sample Text"));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToastIconProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register ("ToastIcon",typeof (ToastIconType),typeof (Toast),new PropertyMetadata (ToastIconType.None,OnToastIconChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsToastVisibleProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register ("IsToastVisible",typeof (bool),typeof (Toast),new PropertyMetadata (false,OnIsToastVisibleChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DurationProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register ("Duration",typeof (TimeSpan),typeof (Toast),new PropertyMetadata (TimeSpan.FromSeconds (10),OnDurationChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageGeometryProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register ("ImageGeometry",typeof (Geometry),typeof (Toast));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue (TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue (TextProperty,value); }
    }

    public bool IsToastVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue (IsToastVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue (IsToastVisibleProperty,value); ChangeVisualState (); }
    }

    public ToastIconType ToastIcon
    {
        get { return (ToastIconType)GetValue (ToastIconProperty); }
        set { SetValue (ToastIconProperty,value); }
    }

    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return (TimeSpan)GetValue (DurationProperty); }
        set { SetValue (DurationProperty,value); }
    }

    public Geometry ImageGeometry
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue (ImageGeometryProperty); }
        set { SetValue (ImageGeometryProperty,value); }
    }

    private static void OnDurationChanged(DependencyObject d,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control=(Toast)d;
        var value=(TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
        control.Duration=value;
    }

    private static void OnIsToastVisibleChanged(DependencyObject d,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var c=(Toast)d;
        var value=(bool)e.NewValue;
        c.IsToastVisible=value;
    }

    private void ChangeVisualState()
    {
        if (IsToastVisible)
        {
            DoubleAnimation da=new DoubleAnimation { From=1,To=0,Duration=TimeSpan.FromSeconds (Duration.Seconds) };

            CubicEase cubicEase=new CubicEase ();
            cubicEase.EasingMode=EasingMode.EaseInOut;

            da.EasingFunction=cubicEase;

            da.Completed+=(sender,e) => IsToastVisible=false;
            BeginAnimation (OpacityProperty,da);
        }
        else
        {
            Opacity=0;
        }
    }

    private static void OnToastIconChanged(DependencyObject d,DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control=(Toast)d;
        var value=(ToastIconType)e.NewValue;

        switch (value)
        {
            case ToastIconType.Information:
                control.ImageGeometry=Geometry.Parse ("M3.6069946,1.8659973C2.6459963,1.8659973,1.8660278,2.6480103,1.8660278,3.6080017L1.8660278,20.546021C1.8660278,21.507019,2.6459963,22.288025,3.6069946,22.288025L11.647035,22.288025 9.6170056,27.481018 18.038026,22.288025 28.124027,22.288025C29.085025,22.288025,29.865054,21.507019,29.865054,20.546021L29.865054,3.6080017C29.865054,2.6480103,29.085025,1.8659973,28.124027,1.8659973z M3.6069946,0L28.124027,0C30.11304,0,31.731998,1.6190186,31.731998,3.6080017L31.731998,20.546021C31.731998,22.536011,30.11304,24.154022,28.124027,24.154022L18.567018,24.154022 5.8439948,32 8.9130261,24.154022 3.6069946,24.154022C1.618042,24.154022,-2.120687E-07,22.536011,0,20.546021L0,3.6080017C-2.120687E-07,1.6190186,1.618042,0,3.6069946,0z");
                break;

            case ToastIconType.Warning:
                control.ImageGeometry=Geometry.Parse ("M13.950004,24.5L13.950004,28.299988 17.950004,28.299988 17.950004,24.5z M13.950004,10.399963L13.950004,21.699951 17.950004,21.699951 17.950004,10.399963z M15.950004,0C16.349998,0,16.750007,0.19995117,16.950004,0.69995117L31.750011,30.099976C31.949993,30.5 31.949993,31 31.750011,31.399963 31.549999,31.799988 31.150005,32 30.750011,32L1.1499981,32C0.75000406,32 0.34999478,31.799988 0.14999761,31.399963 -0.049999204,31 -0.049999204,30.5 0.14999761,30.099976L14.950004,0.69995117C15.150001,0.19995117,15.549995,0,15.950004,0z");
                break;
        }
    }

    public enum ToastIconType
    {
        None=0,
        Information=1,
        Warning=2
    }
}
```

and my toast style:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MetroCustomControls">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Toast}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Toast.Static.Background" Color="LightGray" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Toast.Static.BorderBrush" Color="Gray" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Toast.Static.Foreground" Color="DimGray" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Toast.Static.Background}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Toast.Static.BorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Toast.Static.Foreground}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10" />
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Toast}">
                    <Grid x:Name="template_Root">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                CornerRadius="2"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Path x:Name="path" Margin="6,0,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"  Stretch="Uniform" Width="12" Height="12" Data="{TemplateBinding ImageGeometry}" />
                                <TextBlock  Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Padding="5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ToastIcon,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="None">
                            <Setter TargetName="path" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: where i use toast control?  in main window or use it in every page?

Comment: You can find a greate implementation of a common apporach (DialogService) at https://www.codeproject.com/articles/36745/showing-dialogs-when-using-the-mvvm-pattern

Comment: tnx Fruchtzwerg, i dont use dialoges, i want my toast control overlay other controls and always be on top like android toast notification.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to the issue of Dialogs in MVVM.

The ideal solution is to wrap the functionality in a `DialogService`, or in your case `ToastService`, that you can inject into ViewModels that require it.

So your MainWindow, or root ViewModel has the control, and ability to display Toasts. Then you have a `IToastService` that looks something like this:

```
public class ToastService
{
    public event Action<String> ToastMessageRecieved;

    public void ShowToast(string message)
    {
        ToastMessageRecieved(message);
    }
}
```

The consumer of the `ShowToast` action (the thing that's actually showing the toast), say the RootViewModel, can subscribe to the `ToastMessageRecieved` action:

```
public MyRootViewModel(ToastService toastService)
{
    //keep it as a dependency in case we want to show toasts
    this.toastService = toastService;

    toastService.ToastMessageRecieved += (message) =>
    {
        //here's where you actually show your toast, however that's done
        //MyRootViewModel has the actual UI element reference. It only
        //appears in this one place.
        Toast.Message = message;
    };
}
```

And any other ViewModels that want to display a Toast then use the service:

```
public MyRandomToastGeneratingViewModel(ToastService toastService)
{
    //our service is inejcted as a dependency
    this.toastService = toastService;
}

public void ShowAToastButtonPressed()
{
    toastService.ShowToast("My great toast!");
}
```

Ideally you'll have some kind of dependency injection framework to utilize - but it's worth implementing for this kind of thing. Dialog services, things like your toasts, factories and data access fit well with MVVM and DI.

To have the actual control (the single instance you have) on top of everything else, in the Window or RootView you can simply have it occupying the same grid cell as the normal content. This is how I usually do overlapping controls:

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
        ...>
    <Grid>
        //my normal content
        <myControls:Toast VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

They will occupy the same space, in the order you add them.

Comment: thanks Joe, How do I put it on top of other controls?

Comment: You'd only have a single place that has the Toast Control, right at the root of your application. To have it on top of everything you could just put it a grid after your usual content. I'll put an example in answer.

Comment: @Joe I know this is quite hold but how do you go about displaying the Toast? or giving the ViewModel a reference to that Toast?

Comment: Was 5 years ago so I don't remember the detail, but I mentioned using DI to inject a "ToastService" into components that want to make a toast, that service can have a `displayToast("content", () => action)`. That service can be injected into the toast display component and fire some kind of message to it (or you could use a built in generic message system?).